# Trouble adding webhook url to WhatsApp Business product on Facebook Developers Dashboard

Tags: facebook, webhooks, whatsapp, facebook-webhooks

After selecting the **Whatapp product** on my **Facebook developer** dashboard, I try to add a webhook but it fails to verify the call back URL and get I an error message that says:

> The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later.

The call back URL is set up just fine on my server though and this is what the code looks like:

```
if (ctx.req?.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'my-verify-token') {
      return ctx.req?.query['hub.challenge']
   }
```

It is a **GET** endpoint.

Also, when I check the logs of my app, I realized that **the endpoint is not even being hit**.

Please how do I fix this?

I expected that the webhook will be added once I provided the details.

Comment: _"I realized that the endpoint is not even being hit."_ - but your URL is publicly reachable, or at least reachable for Facebook, yes?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, it is, I hosted it on digital ocean and no authentication is required to hit the endpoint.

Comment: Same problem here, my server endpoint is never called.

Comment: is your endpoint reachable outside localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem here. I was able to get facebook requests by:

1. Use a https default (443) port endpoint: you should not use http://www.example.com/endpoint  or https://www.example.com:8443/endpoint.
2. Add the endpoint domain to app Domain Manager (located in settings).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Still not quite clear on why it was happening--I also hosted my Whatsapp product on Glitch with no issue for the callback. The issue seems to be related to DigitalOcean: I had to change the domain to another one that I owned. Once I changed the URL and hit the endpoint again through the Whatsapp callback URL, it was able to reach the server.

You can add a domain by going to the app settings in DigitalOcean.